# Decryption of Kerberos ticket contents using AES256 keys

Tags: aes, encryption, kerberos

I am using Microsoft CNG functions to decrypt different parts of the Kerberos tickets and encrypted items in Kerberos messages. The decrypted content that I am getting is not the correct one. I was able to decrypt the sample cipher text using the AES256 key with impacket python libraries. I need to use C/C++ code, but the same sample data is not working when I use MS CNG functions. May be there is something that I am missing.

The encryption type is AES256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96 (18). The cipher text is DER encoded and encrypted ENCTGSRepPart (TGS_REP packet).

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

#define NT_SUCCESS(Status)          (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)

#define STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL         ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000001L)

static const BYTE rgbIV[] =
{
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F
};

void PrintBytes(
    IN BYTE* pbPrintData,
    IN DWORD    cbDataLen)
{
    DWORD dwCount = 0;

    for (dwCount = 0; dwCount < cbDataLen; dwCount++)
    {
        printf("0x%02x, ", pbPrintData[dwCount]);

        if (0 == (dwCount + 1) % 10) putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void MyHandleError(const char* psz, NTSTATUS errorCode)
{
    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    int nErrorNumber = GetLastError();
    if (errorCode)
        nErrorNumber = errorCode;
    //Ask Win32 to give us the string version of that message ID.
    //The parameters we pass in, tell Win32 to create the buffer that holds the message for us (because we don't yet know how long the message string will be).
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, nErrorNumber, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    printf("Error:%s, Error number - %x, Error string - %s\n", psz, nErrorNumber, messageBuffer);
    //Free the Win32's string's buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);
}

bool DecryptText(BYTE* cipherTxt, DWORD cipherTxtSize, BYTE* keyBytes, DWORD keyBytesSize)
{
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE       hAesAlg = NULL;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE       hKey = NULL;
    NTSTATUS                status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    DWORD                   cbCipherText = 0,
        cbPlainText = 0,
        cbData = 0,
        cbKeyObject = 0,
        cbBlockLen = 0,
        cbBlob = 0;
    PBYTE                   pbCipherText = NULL,
        pbPlainText = NULL,
        pbKeyObject = NULL,
        pbIV = NULL,
        pbBlob = NULL;
    BYTE algoName[200];
    // Open an algorithm handle.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
        &hAesAlg,
        BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM,
        NULL,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider\n", status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Calculate the size of the buffer to hold the KeyObject.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
        hAesAlg,
        BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
        (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject,    // Size of the key object
        sizeof(DWORD),
        &cbData,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }
    printf("Size of the Key object - %ld\n", cbKeyObject); // 618
    // Allocate the key object on the heap.
    pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);
    if (NULL == pbKeyObject)
    {
        wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Calculate the block length for the IV.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
        hAesAlg,
        BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH,
        (PBYTE)&cbBlockLen,
        sizeof(DWORD),
        &cbData,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }
    printf("BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH - %ld\n", cbBlockLen);  //16
    // Determine whether the cbBlockLen is not longer than the IV length.
    if (cbBlockLen > sizeof(rgbIV))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** block length is longer than the provided IV length\n");
        goto Cleanup;
    }
    // Get algorithm name
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGetProperty(
        hAesAlg,
        BCRYPT_ALGORITHM_NAME,
        (PBYTE)&algoName,
        sizeof(algoName),
        &cbData,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGetProperty\n", status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }
    wprintf(L"algo name - %s\n", (LPWSTR)algoName); //AES

    // Allocate a buffer for the IV. The buffer is consumed during the 
    // encrypt/decrypt process.
    pbIV = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlockLen);
    if (NULL == pbIV)
    {
        wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    memcpy(pbIV, rgbIV, cbBlockLen);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptSetProperty(
        hAesAlg,
        BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE,
        (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC,
        sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC),
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptSetProperty\n", status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }



    // Generate the key from supplied input key bytes.
    // rgbAES128Key - This is normally a hash of a password or some other reproducible data.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(
        hAesAlg,
        &hKey,      // Out: key Handle (BRCYPT_KEY_HANDLE) returned, can be used to encrypt
        pbKeyObject,    // Out: Ptr to buffer that receives Key object from which  hkey can be re-generated.
        cbKeyObject,
        (PBYTE)keyBytes,    // IN: AES256 key 
        keyBytesSize,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey\n", status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }
    //
 // Get the output buffer size.
 //
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(
        hKey,
        cipherTxt,   //cipher text to be decrypted
        cipherTxtSize,
        NULL,
        pbIV,   //IN:OUT - The address of a buffer that contains the initialization vector (IV) to use during decryption.
        cbBlockLen,
        NULL,
        0,
        &cbPlainText,   // out: size of decrypted plain text
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptDecrypt\n", status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    pbPlainText = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbPlainText);
    if (NULL == pbPlainText)
    {
        wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
        goto Cleanup;
    } 

    printf("Requires - %lu bytes for decrypted buffer\n", cbPlainText);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = BCryptDecrypt(
        hKey,
        cipherTxt,   // encrypted cipher text earlier
        cipherTxtSize,
        NULL,
        pbIV,   // In:out - The address of a buffer that contains the initialization vector (IV) to use during decryption.
        cbBlockLen, //In - Size of the pbIV
        pbPlainText,    // Out - Decrypted plain text
        cbPlainText,    // IN - Size of pbPlainText buffer
        &cbPlainText,   // Out - actual size of plain text
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by BCryptDecrypt\n", status);
        MyHandleError("BcryptDecrypt", status);
        goto Cleanup;
    }
    char str[610];
    printf("Decrypted %ld bytes\n", cbPlainText);
    PrintBytes(pbPlainText, cbPlainText);
    HexBytesToString(pbPlainText, cbPlainText, str);
    printf("Plain text - %s\n", str);
    wprintf(L"Success!\n");
    return true;

Cleanup:

    if (hAesAlg)
    {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAesAlg, 0);
    }

    if (hKey)
    {
        BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    }

    if (pbCipherText)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbCipherText);
    }

    if (pbPlainText)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbPlainText);
    }

    if (pbKeyObject)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbKeyObject);
    }

    if (pbIV)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbIV);
    }
    return false;
}

int __cdecl wmain(
    int                      argc,
    __in_ecount(argc) LPWSTR* wargv)
{
    char keyStr[] = "8ab617020bd457ae2e7d85ebec73a4a759d128b5c4dd60b9b5903f936623c3b7";
    BYTE keyBytes[32];
    char cipherTxt[] = "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";
    BYTE cipherBytes[400];
    DWORD cipherBytesSize = 608 / 2;    // This is multiple of block size 16.
    DWORD keyBytesSize = 32;

    if (CryptStringToBinaryA(keyStr, NULL, CRYPT_STRING_HEX, keyBytes, &keyBytesSize, NULL, NULL))
        PrintBytes(keyBytes, keyBytesSize);
    if (CryptStringToBinaryA(cipherTxt, NULL, CRYPT_STRING_HEX, cipherBytes, &cipherBytesSize, NULL, NULL))
        PrintBytes(cipherBytes, cipherBytesSize);
    DecryptText(cipherBytes, cipherBytesSize, keyBytes, keyBytesSize);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've migrated to StackOverflow where these kind of questions are on topic. However, without showing the relevant C++ and C# code it is very unlikely that you get an answer; please [edit] in the code.

Comment: Interesting, what if your actual goal?

Comment: Kerberos doesn't use CBC mode, it uses CTS mode.

Comment: I could not find CTS mode here. Is it called by different name or these APIs do not support it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-property-identifiers

Comment: @Steve "CTS mode" does not exist. CTS means ciphertext stealing. It can be used instead of *padding*. for both CBC and ECB mode. As there is an IV I presume this is CBC + CTS. Just to make things a bit more complicated, there are three related CTS implementations possible. You could build CTS mode from CBC mode, but it's some work.

Comment: I am well aware of what CTS is. My point was that I see nothing in here that would handle the 'stealing' portion of this. BCrypt doesn't expose that functionality so you have to manipulate the IV and first 2 blocks yourself, which is not happening here.